# AJAX ЖИВОЙ ПОИСК undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести в класс `.search-result` все фамилии в которых есть совпадения. Сейчас у меня возвращает `undefined`, хотя  в консоль ajax возвращает 3 модели по запросу "ши".

```
$('.search-user').bind("change keyup click", function(){
    if($(this).val().length >= 2){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{{url('/AjaxUsers')}}", 
            data: {text_input:$(this).val(), _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
            success: function(data) {
                // $.each(data, function(index, data){
                    $(".search-result").html('<li>'+data.fio+'</li>').fadeIn();
                    console.log(data);
                // });
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Если делаю через `each` то возвращает одну последнюю запись, а если пишу просто `data` то выводится `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хрустальный шар говорит, что такое должно сработать

```
success: function(data) {
    var r = data.map(function(v) {
        return '<li>' + v.fio + '</li>';
    }).join('');
    $(".search-result").html(r).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо хрустальному шару))) Работает!